# Getting error while configuring socketIO connection in flutter using socket_io_client ^0.9.12

Tags: flutter, tcp, socket.io, client

I am using `socket_io_client`  ^0.9.12 for Socket communication and in back end i'm using Nodejs and socket.io library.But whenever i run my app i'm getting error  `SocketException: OS Error: timeout , errno = 111, address = *.*.*.*, port = 47772 error, uri = http://**:3001` like this. Here is my code:

```
 IO.Socket socket =  IO.io('http://*.*.*.*:3001/');
  
    socket.onConnect((_) {
      print('connect');
      socket.emit('msg', 'test');
    });
    socket.on('connect_error', (data) => print(data.toString() + "error"));
    socket.on('connect_timeout', (data) => print(data.toString() + "error---"));
    socket.on('error', (data) => print(data.toString() + "error####"));
    socket.on('connect_failed', (error) => {print("ERROR" + error.toString())});
    socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
    socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
    socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));
```